# How to insert yes or no value into flag column based on regex query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-update, where-clause

I have a simple update that works great work analyzing a US based telephone number. It correctly inserts a Y in the phone_flag column based on the following query.

```
UPDATE database.table SET phone_flag = 'Y'
    WHERE id BETWEEN    1 and 100000
      AND (phone REGEXP '[0-9] {10}');
```

I want to insert a N value if it doesn't match the expression, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Query I used.

```
UPDATE database.table
       SET phone_flag = CASE
             WHEN phone = REGEXP [0-9]{10} then 'Y'
             ELSE 'N' END
       WHERE id = '7'
```

Anybody know how to fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: Just get rid of `=` before `REGEXP` and put the regexp in quotes. You had this syntax correct in the first query.

Comment: Note that `REGEXP` matches anywhere in the column. So that will match `abc1234567890xyz`. It will also match a number longer than 10 characters. If it should be exactly 10 characters, anchor it with `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
UPDATE database.table 
SET phone_flag = CASE WHEN phone REGEXP '^[0-9]{10}$' then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
WHERE id = 7
```

Rationale: `REGEXP` is an operator, do not use `=` with it.

Also note that I modified the regex with `^`  at the beginning and `$` at the end: this forces `phone` to contain *exactly* 10 digits (not more, and no other character). You can revert that change if that's not what you wanted.